# Taxonomy term with especial characters and Views Contextual Filter

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I try to use especial characters in Taxonomy. The comma, for example. I want that I can name a term as "Alpha, Beta, Gamma" and I would like that the contextual filter Url may be something like "alpha-beta-gamma". I have tried with alias url and filter by id but it does not work and if I try with an url containing the comma, it works but I don't want those characters to shkw in the Url for SEO purposes. Any idea?